Maven: Create ZIP and store in JAR
In a java project I would like to create a zip archive with a file under src/main/resources and then include that zip in the generated jar artifact.
*The ZIP archive is an AWS lambda implementation used only in tests, hence I'd like to share it across multiple sub-projects with minimum effort.
The structure is:
.
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── resources
│           └── index.js
└── pom.xml

and I'd like the output to be:
.jar
└── function.zip

I've tried using the assembly plugin to generate the ZIP archive but then I couldn't figure out how I can add it in the JAR package. Is there a plugin that combines these actions in that order?

Why do you need to put a zip into a jar file? The jar itself is compressed like a zip? Can you give more details about the details?

Fair point. Just updated the description. Atm I can reference the generated ZIP under the ../module-name/target/function.zip and it works fine. What I wanted to achieve is to add this module as a dependency and then read the zip from the resources directly
